# How does a dataframe know how to sort if the sort column has duplicates

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting

I am sorting a dataframe on "timestamp" and taking the top 40 results from each "date"

```
df_hourly.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_hourly['date'] = df_hourly['timestamp'].dt.date
df_hourly.drop_duplicates(subset=['date', 'symbol'], keep='first', inplace=True)
df_hourly = df_hourly.sort_values(by = ['timestamp'], ascending = [True]).groupby('date').head(40)
df_hourly.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

In the timestamp column there are multiple row with the same "timestamp".

The result is a dataframe that looks like:

,timestamp,symbol,open,high,low,close,volume,trade_count,vwap,SMA_20,PRICESPIKE_5,date
0,2022-10-03 09:00:00-04:00,CCL,7.18,7.21,6.58,6.815,27334311.0,56935.0,6.869257,,-5.209097578870132,2022-10-03
1,2022-10-03 09:00:00-04:00,VRT,9.922,10.77,9.883,10.54,933543.0,6959.0,10.48087,,7.846299810246679,2022-10-03
2,2022-10-03 09:00:00-04:00,CBOE,116.64,117.92,115.92,116.22,41081.0,1197.0,116.424997,,7.5632421270005095,2022-10-03
3,2022-10-03 09:00:00-04:00,APLS,65.3,66.8,59.99,60.215,1262763.0,11018.0,62.204843,,-8.444739682803277,2022-10-03
4,2022-10-03 09:00:00-04:00,RBLX,35.76,35.85,33.605,33.96,4305111.0,29642.0,34.273168,,-5.41813898704357,2022-10-03

How, technically, does a dataframe know what order to place each item if there are duplicates on the sort column. My top 40 list stays the same for multiple runs and then will change from time to time.

I can force the result to be a specific order by

```
df_hourly = df_hourly.sort_values(by = ['timestamp', 'close'], ascending = [True, False]).groupby('date').head(40)
```

But I would like to know how it works when sorting on only 'timestamp'

Answer (score 1):

A complete answer to this question requires a deep dive into the details of various sorting algorithms, which is more than I am prepared to do from the couch on a Saturday morning. :-)

However, it is worth noticing that the `sort_values()` function offers, via the `kind=` parameter, some algorithms which are documented to be *stable*, which means that items that are equal are left in the same order relative to each other as they were before being sorted.

Comment: I didn’t know “stable” was an option. Is stable faster than adding an additional sorting column?

Comment: Hard to say without a detailed analysis of how the various algorithms behave on your actual data. My *guess* is that using a stable sort is faster, simply by doing more work in C and less in Python, but I could very well be wrong about that. Run some benchmarks and find out. =)